# ASP.NET Rich Text Control that supports "replace" fields

Tags: asp.net, rich-text-editor, servercontrols

I am looking at a ASP.NET Rich Text Control which has to support "replace" fields. Basically the user should be able to add special fields to the text from a predefined list of replace fields (example: {CustomerName}, {Company}, etc).
  What are some of the options out here? I know the HTMLEditor in Ajaxtoolkit looks nice but not sure if it has this "replace" field functionality.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to have sure that something works as you wish I recommended to write such control yourself :) then you have 100% sure that control works or not. you can make it dynamically by simply adding your own attributes to the properties of objects from which form should be builded

Comment: I am a little pressed with time on this project, so that would be my least favorite solution.